# sending messages to the main window in a thread in win32

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I am relatively new to working with threads in Win32 api and have reached a problem that i am unable to work out.

Heres my problem, i have 4 threads (they work as intended) that allow the operator to test 4 terminals. In each thread i am trying to send a message to the main windows form with either Pass or Fail, this is placed within a listbox. Below is one of the threads, the remaining are exactly the same.

```
void Thread1(PVOID pvoid)
{
for(int i=0;i<numberOfTests1;i++) {         
    int ret;
    double TimeOut = 60.0;
    int Lng = 1;
    test1[i].testNumber = getTestNumber(test1[i].testName);
    unsigned char Param[255] = {0};
    unsigned char Port1 = port1;

    ret = PSB30_Open(Port1, 16);
    ret = PSB30_SendOrder (Port1, test1[i].testNumber, &Param[0], &Lng, &TimeOut); 
    ret = PSB30_Close (Port1);

    if(*Param == 1) SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,IDT_RESULTLIST1,LB_ADDSTRING,i,(LPARAM)"PASS");
    else SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,IDT_RESULTLIST1,LB_ADDSTRING,i,(LPARAM)"FAIL");
}
_endthread();
}
```

I have debugged the code and it does everything except populate the listbox, i assume because its a thread i am missing something as the same code works outwith the thread. Do i need to put the thread to sleep while it sends the message to the main window?

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Check the return value of `SendDlgItemMessage()` to make sure it is returning `>= 0` indicating success, and not `LB_ERR` or `LB_ERRSPACE` indicating failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want your secondary threads trying to manipulate your UI elements directly (such as the `SendDlgItemMessage`). Instead, you normally want to post something like a `WM_COMMAND` or `WM_USER`+N to the main window, and let that manipulate the UI elements accordingly.

Comment: In general, this is good advice from a design perspective.  However, it is also valid and safe to send messages to UI controls in the main thread from worker threads using `SendMessage()` and related functions, since the messages will not be dispatched to the controls until the main thread pumps its message queue for new messages. This is clearly outlined in the `SendMessage()` documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In theory it should work, yes. At the moment it doesn't (thus the question). Since he needs to do something to make it work anyway, why not do it right? It's not as if it's really a huge amount of extra work.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the responses, SendDlgItemMessage() returns 0 so that is fine, but still nothing within the listbox appears. I am a bit confused by what Jerry is saying about not manipulating UI elements directly (i am used to doing all my work in the main window procedure), can anyone provide a quick example of how to show this in code please. Thanks